# CreateLinkedTokenSource throws ObjectDisposedException. How to correctly and safely dispose a CancellationTokenSource?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

Multiple similar questions have been asked here before.

MSDN states as an important note that [one should always dispose the `CancellationTokenSource` when done with it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads).

OK, but it becomes a little complicated with multithreaded applications and async-await model.

I'm developing a library. The problem I ran into is thatI'm using in several places `CreateLinkedTokenSource` out of a `CancellationToken` received from the user. Shortly, I'm doing it so that I'm able to cancel myself an operation if it takes longer than some time.

Example

```
public async Task<Result> DoAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{ 
    using (var linkedTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken)) 
    {
        // here pass linkedTokenSource.Token further down the line 
        var resultTask = sender.DoAsync(linkedTokenSource.Token); 
        var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout); 
        var completed = await Task.WhenAny(resultTask, timeoutTask); 
        if (completed  == timeoutTask) 
        {
            linkedTokenSource.Cancel(); 
            throw TimeoutException(); 
        }

        return await resultTask;
        // from the point of view of this piece of code
        // we're done with the cancellationTokenSource right? 
        // so I need to dispose the source (done here via `using`)
    }
}
```

However, down the line in different code sections, due to race conditions, it happens that some threads are trying to `CreateLinkedTokenSource` out of `linkedTokenSource.Token` resulting in an `ObjectDisposedException` since the `linkedTokenSource` has already been disposed after the `TimeoutException` was thrown.
This will end up in a `UnobservedTaskException` which will confuse the user if he listens on unobserved exceptions.

Putting a `try-catch` on every `CreateLinkedTokenSource` and silencing the `ObjectDisposedException` line seems again strange for me.

My questions are:

1. Why the `CreateLinkedTokenSource` throws this exception? Is there an explanation for this? Since the `CencellationToken` is a struct, why I shouldn't be able to create a new source out of it? (even in the cancellationToken is cancelled).
2. Any suggestions on how should handle disposing in this scenario?

Comment: This was discussed on GitHub in the CoreClr repo very recently. The behavior was changed to not throw an exception in these cases. This change is not in the Desktop CLR yet. Somewhere, there is a duplicate to this question on Stack Overflow which triggered the .NET fix.

Comment: As @usr said, this was fixed for .NET Core. Just wanted to add the issue link: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/4167. Stephen Toub is a hero!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This will end up in a UnobservedTaskException which will confuse the user if he listens on unobserved exceptions.

Well, sort of. `UnobservedTaskException` is pretty much always going to be a fact of life whenever you use `Task.WhenAny` (and abandon the incomplete task, which is the vast majority of the time `Task.WhenAny` is used).

So, they may get an `ObjectDisposedException` reported to `UnobservedTaskException` instead of an `OperationCanceledException`. Meh; in the `async` world, if you're using `Task.WhenAny`, you really need to ignore `UnobservedTaskException` anyway. Besides, a lot of "not easily cancelable" endpoints will close the underlying handle on cancellation requests, which cause (IIRC) `ObjectDisposedException` anyway.

> Why the CreateLinkedTokenSource throws this exception? Is there an explanation for this?

It's part of those [really, really old Microsoft design guidelines that were written with an '80s OOP mindset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx). I never agreed with MS's Dispose guidelines, preferring a [much simpler model](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/08/how-to-implement-idisposable-and.html) that covers all the same use cases with significantly less mental overhead.

> Any suggestions on how should handle disposing in this scenario?

Just keep it as-is. `UnobservedTaskException` isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you've removed the rest of code with task creation. Whenether, it's very likely that your code is something like this:

```
public async Task<Result> DoAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{ 
    using (var linkedTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken)) 
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // here pass linkedTokenSource.Token further down the line 
            // check if further processing reached some timeout and if it did:
            if (timeout) 
            {
                linkedTokenSource.Cancel(); 
                throw TimeoutException(); 
            }
            // from the point of view of this piece of code
            // we're done with the cancellationTokenSource right? 
            // so I need to dispose the source (done here via `using`)
        }
    }
}
```

So you catch a closure variable, which being used into a `using` construction. So it works like this:

- You enter the `using` block
- You start your task
- You immediately return from the method
- You execute the `finally` block for your method, which [calls the `.Dispose()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for your `linkedTokenSource` variable
- You got a timeout
- you access a disposed closure

You have to rewrite your code for manually disposing the `linkedTokenSource` after you are done with whole task, not when you're done with starting it.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, I filled up all the code in my example, sorry for not doing it from the beggining

Comment: Why mark a method as `async` if you aren't using `await` in your code? What type has the `sender` variable? Your code isn't enough to investigate further.

Comment: Hi @DanDinu. I've seen your code, and I think that it doesn't make much sense: you are awating of the `resultTask` in the moment then it complete, blocking the thread before. You should await the `Task.WhenAny` to realy do the async code.